# Malayalam fonts incorrectly displayed in jasper report PDF(Works in HTML)

Tags: jasper-reports

I need a jasper report PDF using Malayalam font.I used font-extension property,still there are errors in displaying Malayalam. In HTML file there is no issues, only in PDF.  Difference between HTML and PDF file based on some specific letters in Malayalam. font.AnjaliOldLipi-0.730.jar is added in the class path. Tried with many .ttf fonts .I cant understand whats wrong with the code.I need the correct display in Malayalam(as shown in the image(2)).I saw many related articles posted in stackoverflow with different languages but couldn't find a solution.Thanks in Advance. 
[Please check this link](https://www.developer.com/db/how-to-create-a-multilingual-jasperreport.html)

```
Neyyabhishekam (1 Mudra)=നെയ്യഭിഷേകം (1 മുദ്ര ).  
Neyy Vilakku=നെയ് വിളക്ക്.  
NIRANJANAM=നീരാഞ്ജനം.  
Nirayum, Puthariyum=നിറയും പുത്തരിയും.
```

Incorrect display in Malayalam(in PDF)
 [image: Incorrect display in Malayalam(in PDF)]

Correct display in Malayalam

[image: Correct display in Malayalam]

jrxml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<!-- 2018-05-30T12:37:54 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="bbd73fad-6dbf-4e67-9de0-9b6c047f4111">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="DatasetInvoicePoojaCollection" uuid="711a4ab4-6edc-48d3-9b78-78cb149393e2">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="invoiceNo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="poojaName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="quantity" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="singleAmount" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="amount" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <variable name="amount1" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></variableExpression>
        </variable>
        <variable name="amount2" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></variableExpression>
        </variable>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="fromInvoiceNo" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <parameter name="toInvoiceNo" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <parameter name="userName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="ds" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="temple" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="65" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="1" uuid="c212af08-7125-4a66-82ab-9ab03ccd7fd4"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="555" height="22" uuid="7e87adec-fab9-47bd-87b2-282065279c4d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Heading]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="27" y="38" width="259" height="20" uuid="a50627b0-6b2e-42a7-a4c1-a0ef20266d13">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Pooja Collection Report (InvoiceWise)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="340" y="38" width="60" height="20" uuid="4a0b6eb7-ac6f-49ab-8026-d2404006fb53"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Invoice :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="400" y="38" width="150" height="20" uuid="281008a2-8328-440f-ab4f-4bb79fc79324"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromInvoiceNo}.toString()+" - "+$P{toInvoiceNo}.toString()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="446" y="22" width="38" height="16" uuid="e80c8713-b0cc-47c2-93a0-4949d09d8a64"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[User :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="484" y="24" width="70" height="13" uuid="ec8516ca-bb88-4f12-b76b-2868a057b401"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{userName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="1" y="60" width="555" height="1" uuid="b3bb9b2d-3c33-431f-ae08-4cd7b574ebc6"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="14" y="24" width="60" height="14" uuid="76b28118-1f20-4ad9-a903-49cf3f9f1fba"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Temple :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="80" y="23" width="280" height="14" uuid="740b1ae1-ac02-4a31-84a1-554877bbac62"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{temple}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="80" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="80" uuid="d6c6a54d-cecd-424c-a326-dfdf19ad83d8">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="DatasetInvoicePoojaCollection" uuid="45f264a8-a8e7-4ac9-8893-1a10e6c67706">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{ds}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="95698acc-aa28-48ec-8fd7-e118e5f99545">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" uuid="c962e7df-0098-41ff-a2da-ba7c69c09895"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[No]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="25">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" uuid="a93247c4-8628-4c47-b1f8-987643e37869"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="180" uuid="a6c27efc-24d8-44a5-a69e-9a005daa7cdb">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="180" height="25" uuid="8bb145a3-3414-4a5c-bb06-ee11072c6728"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                                    <paragraph leftIndent="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Pooja Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="25">
                            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                                <reportElement style="Table_TD" x="0" y="0" width="180" height="25" uuid="9c758649-aa9d-4ce1-ad47-956da4f05dc5"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                                    <font fontName="AnjaliOldLipi" size="9"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{poojaName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="70ae1e22-57f7-42af-9820-750b16581ad3">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column3"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                            <box>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="25" uuid="f655e6bc-bf98-4fc4-a76b-897fd897a50a"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Number]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="25">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="25" uuid="1d8cfcaf-cc8d-402a-ae2d-f5d34a7d5b36"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="111" uuid="32723547-3a58-4a60-b872-7ad70819a293">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column4"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="1a5496a9-2e0e-47bc-983d-20173c726e17"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[GRAND TOTAL]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableFooter>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="25" uuid="7fd4c349-accc-41bd-a1fa-0ec618d966d0"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                                    <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Rate]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="25">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="25" uuid="cfa798ed-d92c-4971-bb35-7cd5f767436b"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                    <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{singleAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="114" uuid="7c2aa60c-1176-4d15-88b6-9f01a543ad13">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column5"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField pattern="#.00">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="114" height="30" uuid="ffc003df-ab32-4e48-91c1-e4dd35efd1b7"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{amount2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:tableFooter>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="114" height="25" uuid="b11cde18-9982-4c75-981d-5ad3ae250387"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                                    <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Amount]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="25">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="#0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="114" height="25" uuid="0d256f59-19e6-4396-b1b9-ac1b570b100d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                    <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="555" height="1" uuid="96a3bf00-89c8-44a8-a081-9a6cd2d10990"/>
            </line>
            <textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy">
                <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="100" height="14" uuid="82d1c7ab-35b7-4735-b748-0c9fa11d8a5a"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="HH:mm">
                <reportElement x="100" y="2" width="100" height="14" uuid="c896c5d8-2194-41d7-8c4c-54bd5b948725"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Could you paste here one of the texts so that we can try it ourselves?

Comment: നെയ്യഭിഷേകം (1 മുദ്ര )-pasted the text,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Added custom font [Noto Sans Malayalam](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Malayalam) using `jasperreports-fonts` to make it work please see the complet working solution [here](https://github.com/prajinpults/jasper-malayalam)

add maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

create properties for jasperreport-fonts `jasperreports_extension.properties` in resorce file

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.simple.font.families=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.lobstertwo=fonts.xml
```

create `fonts.xml` in same file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<fontFamilies>

    <fontFamily name="NotoSansMalayalam">
        <normal>fonts/NotoSansMalayalam.ttf</normal>
        <bold>fonts/NotoSansMalayalam.ttf</bold>
        <italic>fonts/NotoSansMalayalam.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>fonts/NotoSansMalayalam.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <!--
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'Lobster Two', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
        -->
    </fontFamily>

</fontFamilies>
```

Then update Jasper report to use the font.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<!-- 2018-05-30T12:37:54 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="bbd73fad-6dbf-4e67-9de0-9b6c047f4111">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="DatasetInvoicePoojaCollection" uuid="711a4ab4-6edc-48d3-9b78-78cb149393e2">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="invoiceNo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="poojaName" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="quantity" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="singleAmount" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <field name="amount" class="java.lang.Double"/>
        <variable name="amount1" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></variableExpression>
        </variable>
        <variable name="amount2" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="Sum">
            <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></variableExpression>
        </variable>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="fromInvoiceNo" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <parameter name="toInvoiceNo" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <parameter name="ds" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <parameter name="temple" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="userName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="65" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="1" uuid="c212af08-7125-4a66-82ab-9ab03ccd7fd4"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="555" height="22" uuid="7e87adec-fab9-47bd-87b2-282065279c4d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Heading]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="27" y="38" width="259" height="20" uuid="a50627b0-6b2e-42a7-a4c1-a0ef20266d13">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Pooja Collection Report (InvoiceWise)]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="340" y="38" width="60" height="20" uuid="4a0b6eb7-ac6f-49ab-8026-d2404006fb53"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Invoice :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="400" y="38" width="150" height="20" uuid="281008a2-8328-440f-ab4f-4bb79fc79324"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromInvoiceNo}.toString()+" - "+$P{toInvoiceNo}.toString()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="446" y="22" width="38" height="16" uuid="e80c8713-b0cc-47c2-93a0-4949d09d8a64"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="true"  isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[User :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="484" y="24" width="70" height="13" uuid="ec8516ca-bb88-4f12-b76b-2868a057b401"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="10" isBold="true"  isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{userName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="1" y="60" width="555" height="1" uuid="b3bb9b2d-3c33-431f-ae08-4cd7b574ebc6"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="14" y="24" width="60" height="14" uuid="76b28118-1f20-4ad9-a903-49cf3f9f1fba"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Temple :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="80" y="23" width="280" height="14" uuid="740b1ae1-ac02-4a31-84a1-554877bbac62"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="NotoSansMalayalam" size="10" isBold="true"  isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{temple}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="80" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="80" uuid="d6c6a54d-cecd-424c-a326-dfdf19ad83d8">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="DatasetInvoicePoojaCollection" uuid="45f264a8-a8e7-4ac9-8893-1a10e6c67706">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{ds}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="95698acc-aa28-48ec-8fd7-e118e5f99545">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column1"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" uuid="c962e7df-0098-41ff-a2da-ba7c69c09895"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[No]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="25">
                            <textField textAdjust="ScaleFont" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" uuid="a93247c4-8628-4c47-b1f8-987643e37869"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="180" uuid="a6c27efc-24d8-44a5-a69e-9a005daa7cdb">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column2"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="180" height="25" uuid="8bb145a3-3414-4a5c-bb06-ee11072c6728"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="NotoSansMalayalam" size="9" isBold="true"  isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                                    <paragraph leftIndent="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Pooja Name]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="25">
                            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                                <reportElement style="Table_TD" x="0" y="0" width="180" height="25" uuid="9c758649-aa9d-4ce1-ad47-956da4f05dc5"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                                    <font fontName="NotoSansMalayalam" size="9"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{poojaName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="70ae1e22-57f7-42af-9820-750b16581ad3">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column3"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                            <box>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="25" uuid="f655e6bc-bf98-4fc4-a76b-897fd897a50a"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Number]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="25">
                            <textField textAdjust="ScaleFont" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="25" uuid="1d8cfcaf-cc8d-402a-ae2d-f5d34a7d5b36"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{quantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="111" uuid="32723547-3a58-4a60-b872-7ad70819a293">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column4"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="30" uuid="1a5496a9-2e0e-47bc-983d-20173c726e17"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[GRAND TOTAL]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableFooter>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="25" uuid="7fd4c349-accc-41bd-a1fa-0ec618d966d0"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                                    <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Rate]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="25">
                            <textField textAdjust="ScaleFont" pattern="#0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="111" height="25" uuid="cfa798ed-d92c-4971-bb35-7cd5f767436b"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                    <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{singleAmount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="114" uuid="7c2aa60c-1176-4d15-88b6-9f01a543ad13">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.components.table.model.column.name" value="Column5"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField pattern="#.00">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="114" height="30" uuid="ffc003df-ab32-4e48-91c1-e4dd35efd1b7"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{amount2}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:tableFooter>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="25" rowSpan="1">
                            <box>
                                <bottomPen lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="114" height="25" uuid="b11cde18-9982-4c75-981d-5ad3ae250387"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                                    <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Amount]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="25">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                            <textField textAdjust="ScaleFont" pattern="#0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="114" height="25" uuid="0d256f59-19e6-4396-b1b9-ac1b570b100d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="9"/>
                                    <paragraph rightIndent="3"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="16" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="555" height="1" uuid="96a3bf00-89c8-44a8-a081-9a6cd2d10990"/>
            </line>
            <textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy">
                <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="100" height="14" uuid="82d1c7ab-35b7-4735-b748-0c9fa11d8a5a"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="HH:mm">
                <reportElement x="100" y="2" width="100" height="14" uuid="c896c5d8-2194-41d7-8c4c-54bd5b948725"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```